# Ganache unpredictably drop transactions

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, go-ethereum, ganache

I use "go-ethereum/ethclient" to interact with ganache, for every second, a client will send several transactions (in several threads) to ganache by the API *SendTransaction*. All the transactions will call the same smart contract. Then I check the log file of ganache, it seems that ganache will drop some of the pending transactions while packing blocks (and never pack them).

I have ruled out causes caused by nonce, gasLimit, gasPrice, etc, because I don't get any error as return of the API *SendTransaction*, neither any error msg in the log file of ganache. Besides, in the log, I see the RPC record of every transaction the client sent.
I wonder if this works as expected. If ganache will drop some transactions, what is the criteria ? Is there something concrete I can do to keep the transaction from being dropped?
I would be very grateful if someone could help me resolve my confusion.